# microtype features not applying on italic and bold faces

Tags: luatex, bold, italic, microtype, font-expansion

I'm trying to extend the **microtype** features also to the bold and italic faces of a given font family.

In the sample text, the expansion features apply only to the roman shape.

[image]

This is the source code I used:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[russian, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, factor = 100, expansion=true, shrink = 250, stretch = 250]{microtype}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\setmainfont{Baskerville}%{Avenir Next}

\newcommand\TextSlav{
    \begin{hyphenrules}{russian}
    Христос воскресый из мертвых, смертию смерть поправый и сущим во гробех живот даровавый,
    \end{hyphenrules}
    }
\newcommand\TextLat{
    \begin{hyphenrules}{italian}
    Cristo, il risorto dai morti, che con la morte ha calpestato la morte e ha donato la vita a coloro che stavano nelle tombe,
    \end{hyphenrules}
    }


\begin{document}

\TextLat\\
\TextSlav

\bfseries

\TextLat\\
\TextSlav

\itshape

\TextLat\\
\TextSlav


\end{document}
```

Comment: load `microtype` with the option `expansion=alltext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `microtype` enables font expansion for a limited set of fonts only, in which the bold series is not included. You can choose a different font set by loading `microtype` with:

```
\usepackage[expansion=alltext]{microtype}
```

or after loading the package:

```
\UseMicrotypeSet[expansion]{alltext}
```

All predefined font sets are listed in the documentation, chapter 4, table 2. With the `allmath` set, math fonts would be expanded too, with `all`, well, all fonts.

(The default dates back to the time when `pdftex` had to embed each expanded font instance in the `pdf` file, which could lead to a considerable increase in the file size. With `pdftex` v1.20 or newer, expanding all fonts shouldn't create a large overhead.)